# How to set default selected text in ng-select or ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to AngularJS and I have been reading some answers here but nothing worked out. I have a json file from a controller that I display in a select. I want to set the selected value based on the text value.This is what I have so far.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="userModule" ng-controller="userCtrl">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>User Name:</label> <br />
        <select ng-model="users.selectedUser" class="form-control" ng-options="item.UserName as item.UserName for item in users.availableOptions"></select>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
<script>
var _$http;
var _$scope;
var oldUser = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["UserName"]));
var oldRole = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["RoleName"]));
angular.module('userModule', [])
    .controller('userCtrl', xConstructor);

function xConstructor($scope, $http) {
    _$http = $http;
    _$scope = $scope;
    $http.get("/RoleManagement/GetUserData").then(xReceive);
    $http.get("/RoleManagement/GetRoleData").then(roleReceive);

    _$scope.submit = function () {
        //alert("Here:" + _$scope.selectedUser);
        $http.get("/RoleManagement/PutUserRoleData?UserId=" + _$scope.selectedUser.UserId + "&RoleId=" + _$scope.selectedRole.RoleId).then(writeSuccess);
    }

}

function xReceive(userObject) {
    _$scope.users = {
        availableOptions: userObject.data,
        **selectedUser: { UserId: oldId, UserName: oldUser } //What to put here?**
    };

    alert(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(_$scope.users.selectedUser));
}
</script>
```

Or any other suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: _I want to set the selected value based on the text value._ which text value ?

Comment: Use [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) directive.

Comment: What does userObject in xReceive look like?

Comment: @TyKroll The text value is based on the ViewData from the backend. oldUser and oldRole. userObjejct is a json data with UserName and UserId as members

Comment: Looks like userObject.data is a list of your users. You need to select your selectedUser from that data via oldUser. It would be better to user oldUserId, if possible.

Comment: @TyKroll Yes, that is what I did. I even hardcoded selectedUser: { UserId: oldId, UserName: oldUser } with an existing value but it stll doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not mapping the model to any element in the array you have.
Assuming you have the id of the user you want to select this is what you do:

```
 function xReceive(userObject) {
        _$scope.users = {
            availableOptions: userObject.data,
            selectedUser: null
        };

        let selectedUser;
        for (let i = 0; i < userObject.data.length; i++) {
          if (userObject.data[i].id === oldId) {
           selectedUser = userObject.data[i];
           break;
          }
        }
        if (selectedUser) {
          _$scope.users.selectedUser = selectedUser;
        }
        alert(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(_$scope.users.selectedUser));
    }
```

Also note, you can do this to just select the first one:

```
_$scope.users.selectedUser = _$scope.users.availableOptions[0];
```